# How to count comments?

Tags: eclipse, comments, code-metrics

I'm trying to count the total lines of code, and **most importantly the lines of comments**!

I am currently using eclipse, and I have tried metrics2 for eclipse but it only gives total lines of code, which ignores whitespace and comments.

Could anyone suggest how I can get this value please

Thanks

Comment: Do you insist on using Eclipse for this?

Comment: @IraBaxter No, I just mentioned it as its my currently preferred IDE. I also have netbeans, but I will try an external program, I just need a quick count it's not a long term requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/). It is simple to use and supports a bunch of languages.

Comment: Thanks very much, did exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 1):

[CodePro Analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/metrics/metrics.html) is an Eclipse plug-in that collects Java metrics including counting comments.

Comment: +1 Because the link looks really good. I'm not changing the accepted answer until I try it out though! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need this only once, and you don't mind it being slightly wrong, you can use a regular expression to hunt for comment start indicators, and simply count the number of hits.   My unix is bit rusty, but I think you want something like

```
grep -r '.*/[\*/]' yourdirectory | wc
```

This finds lines that apparantly have a comment start in them, and then "counts".  wc produces three numbers: line count, word count, character count; the first value is line count and corresponds to the number of hits, therefore the *number of comments* encountered.

If you want the *number of comment lines*, this will badly undercount multiline /* ...  */ comments; you'll get a lower bound.   But then, you wanted a fast answer.